# Inflate Listview with button using fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, xamarin

I have a main layout containing a listView a EditText and a button. There is another file called row.axml layout containing a TextView and an ImageView. I created a class AddItem.cs (Fragment) that adds an item in the listView contained in Main.axml. But I did not understand how to call the class Additem.cs to add a new item in listview with the text entered in the EditText.

Main.Axml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ListView android:id="@+id/in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Row.Axml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/singleContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_green"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Hello bubbles!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        ImageButton btAdd = FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id.btnAdd);

        _ListOfTexts = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.in);

        btAdd.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        string txtAdded = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.edit_text_out).Text;
        //add new row 
        };
    }
```

Additem.cs

```
public class AddItem: Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

http://warting.github.io/AndroidChatBubbles/

Comment: What do you mean by 'how to call the class' ?

Comment: @Gumbo. Making class AddItem add items in listview from the Main class (MainActivity)

Comment: So the fragment `AddItem` contains a listview to which you want to  add items from the fragments parent Activity? What have you tried/ what code is not working?

Comment: @Gumbo AddItem is a fragment that adds new rows to the ListView that is Main.axml. So when the add button is clicked a new row is added. The layout of this new row is set in Row.Axml

Comment: And you want to add a row from the Activity?

Comment: @Gumbo yes, i want to add a new row with the layout Row.axml fragment using the AddItem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a public method to add an item in `addItem` and call it from the parent activity.

Comment: i could, but the new item is overwriting the previous item. It's not like a list.